# How to read provising file in ios

Tags: ios

I am adding provisioning profile file in my resource section. Now I got the path of file using

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"5B989A53-9KD3-4B1F-9499-384AEFH3B0FE" ofType:@"mobileprovision"];
```

Now, I want to see the content of file using following command

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

and when I am printing content using NSlog its showing nothing.

As we all know, .mobileprovising file is in XML format.(open in text editor).

please tell me how to parse or read content.

Comment: Is the `path` string holding the path of your file. Did you check this first?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourProvisioningFile"
                                                 ofType:@"mobileprovision"];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isExisted = [fm fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSError *err;
if (isExisted) {
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                         encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                            error:&err];

    NSLog(@"%@",content);
}else{
    NSLog(@"%@",err);
}
```

**Edit**: If it prints some strange character at the beginning of `content` variable. Open this provisioning file and delete these strange character so that it has right format `XML`.